# I just switched to Ubuntu as my OS and when I shut down it won't automatically reboot when I turn the computer back on. Why?

Tags: boot, 15.04, shutdown

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04 32-bit. It works fine except when I shutdown and turn it back on, the computer just goes to a black screen as if there's no OS.  I can get around this by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> while the computer is booting, and it will go to the GRUB bootloader, and then just boot from there and everything's fine.  It's just annoying and I want it to work correctly.

I've tried:

- re-installing Ubuntu
- fixing the problem through GRUB in repair mode.

I'm new to Linux so dumb down your advice if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T) and try

```
sudo poweroff
sudo shutdown -h now
```

And then enter your password. If it works then you can make your bash script and use that.

Also did you find on search engine? Please search with your computer module number and poweroff problem then you might can find something.

I think that you need some grub options to fix this related to ACPI etc.
You might try this:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

change this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off"
```

or

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"
```

then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

and then restart computer and try to shutdown.